# ngrx/store subscribe being called multiple times. Best place to unsubscribe?

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-store

I have an angular component that contains a NgModal popup.

I am subscribing to the ngrx store in the component.

The component's ngOnDestroy is never called because a new route is never called.

The user add's new Users via the modal popup.

The subscription(select) to the store for the 'user' state never unsubscribes and is being called many times.

What is the best way to handle the unsubscribing from a store.select() when ngOnDestroy() is never called?

Comment: Don't you have a hint from the popup when it is being closed? So that you could store the subscription within the popups component and then unsubscribe it when it is being closed?

Comment: The issue is that I dispatch a message when the modal closes so that I can get the post success response back to the parent.  I will try to subscribe when the modal is opened and unsubscribe when I receive the post success message.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way around this issue is don't `subscribe` in your component, do it in the template through the `async` pipe.

From the [Angular Docs](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe):

> The async pipe **subscribes** to an Observable or Promise and returns the latest value it has emitted. When a new value is emitted, the async pipe marks the component to be checked for changes. When the component gets destroyed, the async pipe **unsubscribes automatically** to avoid potential memory leaks (emphasis added).

Since you mentioned `ngOnDestroy` is not called, then most likely the component persists and is hidden/shown as needed, in which case you'll just get the single subscribe.

You can also prevent multiple `subscribe` calls in the template by using the "async as" pattern, [as explained by Todd Motto here.](https://toddmotto.com/angular-ngif-async-pipe). Basically, when encountering the need for multiple `async` pipes in a template, use `*ngIf="data$ | async as data"` at a higher element and reference the resolved `data` below.

Comment: I came to this question having similar issue and, indeed, what solved my problem was that hint given by Todd Motto, using 'as data'. In my concrete case I was using the async pipe multiple times in my html and, of course, that was causing multiple subscriptions. Thanks John.

Answer (score 1):

Destroying the Subscription inside **ngOnDestroy()** is useful, if you don't want that subscription to be called in different components

However, if the subscription is getting called multiple time within the same component you can solve this by using **RxJs Operators**

```
yourSelectorname$.pipe(skip(1)).pipe(take(1)).subscribe
```

or

```
yourSelectorname$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe
```

It depends according to your need